# Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.1.4 via registry

Tags: angular, cordova, meteor, ionic2, angular2-meteor

i'm following this tutorial here and got the following error when i tried to run android. internet is ok.
https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/meteor/setup

```
C:\Work\whatsapp>meteor run android
[[[[[ C:\Work\whatsapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
Subproject Path: CordovaLibns                -
Subproject Path: CordovaLibns                [=======                   ] 25% 17.2s
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding plugin ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.1.4 to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.1.4 via registry.
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
   Error: version not found: ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.1.4
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the
   Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose
   the issue.)

C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\barbatus_typescript\0.6.6\plugin.typescript.os\npm\nod
e_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the error message carefully you can find it that the error is coming from the incorrect version number of the plugin:

> Error: version not found: ionic-plugin-keyboard@1.1.4

Try to use the latest version of ionic-plugin-keyboard @2.2.1

you can check the release versions here : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard/releases

Comment: This solution worked. Thanks.
`meteor add cordova:ionic-plugin-keyboard@2.2.1`